# expected value normal distribution (simple question)

Tags: calculus, probability

How do I compute

> $$\int_a^\infty x \frac{e ^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2} }{\sqrt2\pi}dx$$

Comment: Put $-1/2x²$ as $u$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitute $-\dfrac{1}{2}x^2=t$
Therefore, $xdx=-dt$

$$\int^{\infty}_{a}x\frac{e^{{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}}}{\sqrt{2}\pi}=\int^{-\infty}_{-\frac{1}{2}a^2}{-e^t}dt$$

$$-\int^{-\infty}_{-\frac{1}{2}a^2}{\dfrac{e^t}{\sqrt{2}\pi}}dt=-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}\pi}[e^t]^{-\infty}_{-\frac{1}{2}a^2}$$

$$Ans: \dfrac{e^{-\frac{1}{2}a^2}}{\sqrt{2}\pi}$$

Comment: why is it that xdx = -dt

Comment: Because we assumed $-\dfrac{1}{2}{x^2}=t$ Differentiating this equation wrt $x$ =>$-\dfrac{1}{2}{2x}=\dfrac{dt}{dx}=>-x=\dfrac{dx}{dt}$ Therefore $-xdx=dt$ or $xdx=-dt$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  $\frac d {dx} (-e^{-\frac   1 2 x^{2}})= xe^{-\frac   1 2 x^{2}}$

Comment: and then integration by parts?

Comment: @EmilKrabbe No, $\int_a^{\infty} f'(x)dx=f(\infty)-f(a)$.